# Xcode won’t use localization files despite matching IDs

Tags: xcode, localization

I have a bunch of elements in Xcode 5’s Interface Builder which I need to translate. I’m using Object ID of those elements to localize, like this:

```
/* Class = "NSButtonCell"; title = "Automatically copy link to clipboard"; ObjectID = "eee-18-aaH"; */
"eee-18-aaH.title" = "Copier automatiquement le lien dans le presse-papier";
```

I checked IDs fifteen times and they match. However, Xcode won’t pull those in when I test the app. Everything else is translated but strings based on Object IDs won’t update.

Both Project → Clean and Window → Organizer → Projects → Derived Data → Delete didn’t work.

What works is unchecking localization from the project and checking it again. After replacing text, Xcode starts localizing those strings.

But this means we need to update dozens of strings across 18 localizations. There has to be a better way to ask Xcode to obey. Ideas?

Comment: Did you ever found a solution to this issue?